# Typescript property only allowed if another property exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Say I have a function in which I want to only allow a property if another property is present.

I tried to do it like this, but it returns with error  `Property 'c' does not exist on type 'A'.`

```
type A = {
  a?: string;
} & ({ b: string; c?: string } | { b?: string });

const sad = (props: A) => {
  const { a, b } = props;

  const { c } = props;  // Property 'c' does not exist on type 'A'.

  return { a, b };
};
```

Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way i know is [User defined Type Guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) and i like to combine it with [Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types)

```
interface CommonProps {
    a?: string
    b?: string
}

interface SimpleProps extends CommonProps {
    kind: "simple"
}

interface ComplexProps extends CommonProps {
    kind: "complex"
    c?: string
}


type Props = SimpleProps | ComplexProps

function isComplex(arg: Props): arg is ComplexProps {
    return arg && arg.kind === 'complex'
}

const sad = (props: Props): any => {
    if (isComplex(props)) {
        const {a, b, c} = props
        // do something
        // return something
    }
    const { a, b } = props
    // do something
    // return something
}
```

In a nutshell, i create an interface for each possible combinations of properties. Then i Union them under the `Props` types, and in my function i use the `user defined guards` to access the properties.

Comment: doesn't work if you try to use Props as class interface, like `class A implements Props`. Is there way to do it without union types?

Answer (score 0):

Union types only keep the properties that are common to the two types. In the following union, the resulting type only has one property: `b : string | undefined`

```ts
{ b: string; c?: string } | { b?: string }
```

The following code will achieve what you originally expected, I think:

```ts
type A = {
  a?: string;
} & ({ b: string; c?: string; } | { b?: undefined; c?: undefined; });

const sad = (props: A) => {
  const { a, b } = props;

  if (b) {
    const { c } = props;

    return { a, b, c };
  }

  return { a, b };
};
```

Outside of the condition, you cannot use `c`, but inside of it the type of `props` has been narrowed down. Now that `b` cannot be `undefined`, the compiler is aware of `c`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to produce this with only types and generics:

```
type SelectedOptional<Base, T extends (string | number | symbol) & keyof Base> = {
  [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key];
} & {
  [Key in T]: Base[Key];
};

type SelectedNever<Base, T extends string | number | symbol> = {
  [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key];
} & {
  [Key in T]?: never;
};

export type Dependant<BaseAttributes, DependantAttributes extends keyof BaseAttributes> =
  | SelectedOptional<BaseAttributes, DependantAttributes>
  | SelectedNever<BaseAttributes, DependantAttributes>;
```

You specify your base attributes which contains all of your attributes (also the dependant ones), then you specify which 2 (or more) are dependant on each other as follows:

This will work:

```
const exampleObject: Dependant<SomeBaseAttributes, 'dependant1' | 'dependant2'> = {
  attr1: 1,
  attr2: 2, 
 };
```

This will fail, because you need to specify attribute 'dependant2' also:

```
const exampleObject: Dependant<SomeBaseAttributes, 'dependant1' | 'dependant2'> = {
  attr1: 1,
  attr2: 2,
  dependant1: 3
};
```